# Weird encoding in executable files in ios apps

Tags: ios

I'm trying to see how does certain ios apps executable files look like, what I do is export the app files to my computer using iexplorer, I then took a look at the `info.plist` to see the executable files, after that I opened them with my notepad to use the UTF-8 Encoding, but here how does things look like in both files-in the opening of both of the files I see english words that are expressing directories:

Sample of file 1:

```
‹"Ò.(?!ÑNÓU£C°îXjøe”Ú5O•½°{^ÿÝŒEÌrôðæ$@[3,ÔÜ£æ»8I˜hGw!*aHÒQ•tœl²þ„™AÍçßÍæ†´³)è:cÌ7H5æß-eFç¯î&Ø\n,$Ë$y»¥ÁB^6ÙP; i(q,AÅ 
âðð·'©=Ÿa"v!PBÛÚ"¤¬‹Wj·;ËsÌŽÚâZüŠ–ÇüÉ;ÜA´sI«¸Üæ¿÷ ›‚‰.êøLž
```

Sample of file 2:

```
ßêª§gö«húDªÝn¡±CÅÁ¹ â=Ø‰ˆ4|®b¡  JeW-É¯ðó<n!¿mªJŒS£šŠ¿)ÙP"ã¢œÛôRW­³tÖÙiŠ/7’¬(.æIó£™\NÒèË0¾jDçéM«Q/rªa`NÌhó¾ByUkézAµI—Ê6èøÁœ.gÄkß±ŠÊbN¬9ó9XˆU_ô°Š Y—9cÍq²Xi“¢•¢^+3Ø¨ñTÒ¦”¦Ø+PEOÖ–lci5^?÷¤(131dv°t]†™6>¦xgýgeéÀXœH7ßJÉ" 3‡rÜ6ÒI_   ƒr cdÅá¸|íð¼l;Töl±”›MÛ˜±o/ôÇô#¬RS;Y¥!ÜzGò“vî©6ØR¡‚>Ì0m5
ŸzrPÐiDMÊ|Þ·9âëYß,pØƒ‹£x—.àN5îüÝrjœG]Æ·
```

Ironically in the second file I can see a huge block of english words absolutely fine, but I dont get it why I don't see the whole file very good? I have also tried to open the files in an objective-c compiler after I have made them `.m` but that again was useless?

Comment: They're compiled binaries. You'd need some kind of decompiler to make any sense of it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS applications consist of compiled code and additional support files, you would need decompilation tools of some kind to get back from the compiled code to readable source. As a starter see

- [IPA File Format](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/IPA_File_Format)
- [.ipa (file extension)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_(file_extension))
- [Bundle Programming Guide/Bundle Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html)

If you just want to understand how iOS apps are developed you might be better of by looking at sample code within Apple's Developer Documentation and/or some of the various online repositories/courses.